# My collection have difference array how can I merge this array javascript?

Tags: javascript, meteor, aggregate

I have a problem with my array. I want to merge different arrays together. Different arrays can be more than that. I will show my collection below.

```
    let myCollection = [
      {
        _id: '0003',
        avgCost: 10,
        itemId: '0003',            
        onHand: 12,
        inventoriesValue: 120,
      },
      {
        _id: '0001',
        avgCost: 20,
        itemId: '0001',            
        onHand: 12,
        inventoriesValue: 240,
      },
      {
        _id: '0001',
        avgCost: 20,
        itemId: '0001',            
        onHand: 10,
        inventoriesValue: 200,
      }
    ]
```

I want to combine elements by itemId to achieve the result below.

```
    [
      {
        _id: '0003',
        avgCost: 10,
        itemId: '0003',            
        onHand: 12,
        inventoriesValue: 120,
      },
      {
        _id: '0001',
        avgCost: 20,
        itemId: '0001',            
        onHand: 22,
        inventoriesValue: 440,
      },     
    ]
```

Comment: I think you should explain more, what query are you using to get the results?

Comment: Do you mean "merge different objects with same _id" in an array? I don't see more than one array in your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, you are trying to perform a union on the two arrays but with an object comparison. There are a few ways to do this.

If you are using `lodash`, you can do something like this with two arrays:

```
_.unionWith(arr1, arr2, _.isEqual);
```

Alternatively, if you have an array of arrays, you could do this:

```
_.uniqWith(_.flatten(arrays), _.isEqual);
```

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood your question. My apologies.

Comment: You can see my collection and result you will understand

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a new array that sums up any identical elements in an original array. The code below should be fine for small arrays.

```
const targetArray = []; // an empty array for the results
myCollection.forEach(mc => { // loop over the original array
  let i = targetArray.findIndex(ta => ta.itemId == mc.itemId); // match on itemId
  if (i > -1) { // found a match
    targetArray[i].onHand += mc.onHand; // increment the onHand value
    targetArray[i].inventoriesValue += mc.inventoriesValue; // and inventoriesValue
  } else { // no match found
    targetArray.push(mc); // push the element
  }
});
```

Note that this assumes that the `avgCost` in each element is the same. If they are different then you'll need to take a weighted average based on the new inventory you're adding in.